# Ubuntu docker-compose wrong Compose file version

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose in an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. My docker-compose version is `docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown`. When I try building, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

How do I upgrade to the latest version of docker-compose on Ubuntu to fix this?

The file looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    ...
networks:
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show us the beginning of the docker-compose file? At least `version` and `services`?

Comment: For 3.8, I think you need Docker compose 1.27.0+. Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Comment: I ran `sudo apt install docker-compose` to install docker-compose. What do I run to upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: You can try to run `sudo apt update` and run `sudo apt upgrade docker-compose`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using features from "3.8", the easiest is to downgrade the version number in your "docker-compose.yml". For the [1.25.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.0) release, that looks like no greater than "3.7" or "2.4".

To upgrade your compose install, the readme on the git repo has [various options for installing docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/#where-to-get-docker-compose). My preference, until the `docker compose` command is bundled in the Linux install, is to use `pip install docker-compose`.

Comment: The pip install docker-compose fixed this issue for me right away!